# Airflow "Variable is not defined"

Tags: airflow

I am working on an Airflow task that strips values from URL parameters.

I've used the same exact format - !set three variables, use schema, read $row_count at the end, etc.

This is the only task that is throwing an error.

```
!set stop_on_error=True
!set exit_on_error=True
!set variable_substitution=True

USE schema myDatawarehouse;

/*
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE web_page_views (
      anonymous_id VARCHAR(80),
      email VARCHAR(765),
      utm_campaign VARCHAR(765)
);
*/

BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE marketing_digital_traffic AS
   SELECT   anonymous_id
            , email
            , split_part(split_part(url, 'utm_campaign=', 2), '&', 1) utm_campaign
   FROM     segment.pages;

SET row_count = &__rowcount;

INSERT INTO etl.load_table(
    table_name
,   rows_inserted
,   job_message
)
values (
           'web_page_views'
       ,   $row_count
       ,   'etl process finished successfully'
)
;

commit;
```

When I run this task I get the error `Variable  is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is the ampersand ("&") in the select statement.

Airflow/python is interpreting that as the beginning of a new variable.

To avoid this, change `'&'` to `'&&'` within the Airflow task like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE marketing_digital_traffic AS
   SELECT   anonymous_id
            , email
            , split_part(split_part(url, 'utm_campaign=', 2), '&&', 1) utm_campaign
   FROM     segment.pages;
```

**NOTE**: You will get this error *even if* your SQL code is commented out. I learned this the hard way.